# Breaking in with sleight of hand

Tags: internal-consistency, security

1. You can perform perfect sleight of hand and pickpocketing. Safely assume that if something isn't physically secured to someone's body, it can be yours. The only person who would notice is the victim the next time they go for their wallet or keycard.
2. You have no sophisticated tools. No lockpicking, no suction cups, no wires, no masks and voice changers.
3. Not all video surveillance is watched with an eagle eye. You don't exactly look like someone recognizable, but if you're somewhere you aren't allowed (barring a bank vault), someone would have to confront you to discover you're an intruder. Keeping a low profile can get you through some secure areas unmolested, but don't push your luck.
4. It's no good to stick around too long. You have basically a full work-day (or 24 hours, if you hide in the bathroom til nightfall) to pull off your heist.

My question is: **What is the most secure area in the world you could gain access to, and what could you do once you were there before diseappearing without a trace?** At what point do modern physical security measures defeat access attempts possible via pickpocketing?

Alternatively, **What's the biggest amount of wealth you could easily accrue in a day given these rules, if you're reasonably sure you could stay anonymous?**

It is my intention to make this question a little videogamey (think *Hitman*), so feel free to offer rule suggestions that, while not necessarily 100% realistic, fit into the realms of both reasonable and interesting. However, real information regarding physical security measures in military, governmental, and corporate settings is very welcome.

Comment: Question: Does the 1-day question include time for planning, or just 1 day of activity after planning?  Are we talking about a crime of convenience or a planned heist?

Comment: @GrinningX assume you've planned and have reasonable working knowledge of your target, but don't know anything a civilian would have no way of knowing. You're outside the secured area as far away as necessary for you to be just any ordinary civilian. If it's Area 51, for example, you've just stopped your car on the closest public road. :)

Comment: Please also assume that your actions being caught on camera isn't the end of the world. Only if it leads to you being found at some later date.

Comment: Well if you can break in without a trace then it isn't secure.

Comment: Is your agent also skilled at reverse pickpocketing? For example you plant a tool on a checkpoint guard before he searches you, then retrieve it before you move on?

Comment: @Kys yes, if you can describe it in a scenario believably.

Comment: Maybe this question is best answered by just listing extremely secure locations and letting the author evaluate which ones are accessible?

Comment: @SRM I am also asking for practical information on current physical security standards in the 2nd clause of my question, because I suspect the scenario where a dude walks into NORAD is maybe a little far-fetched.

Comment: One sidenote -- there are areas you *can* gain access to by these means, but *shouldn't*, due to the safety hazards they can pose to your would-be-thief....

Comment: You don't seem to be trying to build anything with this question, other than the effectiveness of a character in your story. Additionally, I would like to think we wouldn't be posting "real information regarding physical security measures" because of security concerns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mainly storage areas/warehouses. Older businesses what can't afford to upgrade to electronic locks, monitoring systems, or the like. Criminal enterprises (drug stash in the trunk of a car, for example). These are places what still use physical keys, maybe even a keycard, but don't have retinal scans, fingerprint sensors, or keypads that require a code.

Most sensitive areas, such as a bank secure vault, corporate/government data storage, casino cash room, etc will have combination security that requires BOTH a physical key and a passcode to prevent the type of theft you are describing. Or they have human security to visually verify identification. Simply stealing keys and ID badges isn't going to defeat these levels of security.

But a pawn shop, shipping warehouse full of fenceable goods, local drug dealers house; these places may rely more on traditional locks or keycards because they have a very small number of keys and people with access. These places can't afford the expense of a fancy digital security system. A safe may have a combination or digital lock though, there are few that can be opened with just a key. Of course a key may open a lockbox that has the combination written on a sheet of paper.

Of course lots of things can be written down and then be pickpocketed. A flash drive full of stolen credit cards. Access codes to bank accounts, etc. In that sense the thief has to research the transport of INFORMATION, that is what he is stealing. In the modern era transmitting information electronically can be very risky, so good old fashioned hand delivery is still a popular method. So imagine a terrorist carrying bank accounts on a scrap of paper to various cells. Or a mobster with a list of credit cards on a thumb drive. Total value is probably not that high, tens of thousands of dollars most likely.

Of course the absolute highest value pickpocketable item would be a winning Powerball ticket. No idea how a lotto winner gets his ticket verified, but I imagine it must be physically carried into a lottery office, so the thief could intercept the winner (or his lawyer) upon arrival to the lottery office and steal it then (or better yet, swap it out with a ticket with very similar numbers if possible) then claim the winning ticket for himself. Some states allow the winner to remain anonymous behind a shield of lawyers as well, so the thief would be virtually unassailable and would have ample funds to defeat the inevitable lawsuit raised by the initial winner. Since they know when and where each ticket is sold, there would be some ability for the rightful owner to "prove" the ticket is his with store video cameras. Of course these camera tapes are usually located in the managers office, which usually only requires a key, so the super pickpocket can probably get to them easily :)